# Drupal won't update textfield from a integer value with no decimal to the same value with a .0 decimal

Tags: 8, forms

I am facing a strange situation in Drupal 8 where the value of a text field won't be updated in some situations.

Indeed, if the textfield's value is an integer, for instance `19` and I try to update it for a decimal with a `.0` (for instance `19.0`) then it won't be updated. *(My guess is that Drupal takes those 2 values as the same, and so doesn't update the database)*. The same problem happen if I try to update from `19.0` to `19`.

However if I update the value from `19` or `19.0` to any other value (let's say `19.1`) and then go back to `19.0` or `19`, then it will be updated since the numerical value has been different between the two values I am trying to update.

What's strange is that the field I am using is a textfield, and so the string value `"19"` isn't supposed to equals `"19.0"`. I would understand why a numerical field was not updated (since the value is *numerically* the same) but this shouldn't be the case in a textfield.

**My question is, has anybody ever faced a situation like that in Drupal and is there a possible workaround ?** The difference between those two values is important in my situation (even if it is numerically the same)...

Comment: Where are you adding the text field? Is it on something like node edit form? Or is it part of a custom form you made?

Comment: @Matt Yes it is in a node edit form (in the administration section)

Comment: @obrassard What is the field type for that input?